# django looping in template with listview

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I am relatively new to django and python, and I have been struggling lately with a `for loop` problem within a list view on my template.
So, I generate a vanilla list view, and then add `data` to my context processor. the `data` looks like so:

```
data = [
({'map_b': u'britney'}, {'map_s': u'rock'}, {'map_u': u'http://bhc.com/'}), 
({'map_b': u'britney'}, {'map_s': u'pop'}, {'map_u': u'http://hjgjkpop.com'})
({'map_b': u'britney'}, {'map_s': u'sport'}, {'map_u': u'http://hjgjksp.com'})
({'map_b': u'britney'}, {'map_s': u'default'}, {'map_u': u'http://hjgjkde.com'})
({'map_b': u'kate perry'}, {'map_s': u'rock'}, {'map_u': u'http://kpbhc.com/'}), 
({'map_b': u'kate perry'}, {'map_s': u'pop'}, {'map_u': u'http://kphjgjkpop.com'})
({'map_b': u'kate perry'}, {'map_s': u'sport'}, {'map_u': u'http://kphjgjksp.com'})
({'map_b': u'kate perry'}, {'map_s': u'default'}, {'map_u': u'http://kphjgjkde.com'})
({'map_b': u'bon jovi'}, {'map_s': u'default'}, {'map_u': u'http://bjkphjgjkde.com'})
]
```

Now, in my template, I would like to check the value of the above `data` against the value on my `object_list` from my listview. To this end, I do something like this:

```
{% for i in object_list %} # i contants i.b, i.s and i.o

    {% for b, s, u in data %}
        {% if b.map_b|lower in i.b|lower and s.map_s|lower in i.s|lower %}
    <a class="lead" href="{{u.map_u}}" rel="nofollow">
        [{{i.b}}] {{i.s|title|truncatechars:100}}
    </a>
    <h5># Fun Fact: {{ i.o|truncatechars:100 }} @ {{i.b}}</h5>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

So, what I am trying to do is, check `if b.map_b is in i.b` and `if s.map_s in i.s`, then display the `u.map_u`. It works fine, but what I would like to add is an additional condition that if it cannot get `b.map_b and s.map_s to match i.b and i.s`, then display the `u.map_u` corresponding to `i.b and "default"` In short, I would like to use the "default" `map_u` value when it cannot find the above.

I have not been able to see how I can achieve this - and I would appreciate any guidance on this.

I hope I have explained the question well - but maybe not :(

Comment: Dude, sorry the code is bit confusing without seeing everything.  It seems if your logical operator works and you're just trying to display something if it doesn't work why not just add the {% else %} and put it there.

Comment: @chawk: I agree with you - the code is a bit confusing :(( The problem is, if I use an `else` loop as you have suggested, I get hit by a `double entry` of it :( - one with the condition being satisfied, and one with the `else`. presumably, this is because I am `for looping` my `data` context variable :(

Comment: I can't understand what the `i.b` that you're comparing with is supposed to be. `i` is the tuple itself, and it doesn't have any attributes names `b`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: the `i` comes from looping through the listview object_list. This does not seem a  problem really - I can conveniently output these values using the loop as above.

Comment: OK, well then your data does not match what you have posted, which makes it very hard for us to help you. More descriptive variable names would also help.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I am wondering why you say that `i` cannot have `i.b`. For example, on my template, when I do `{% for i in object_list %} {{i.b}} {% endfor %}` it clearly shows me all the entries which I expect. here, "object_list" is returned from a queryset. Just wondering if I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I thought `i` was each row in `data`, rather than the element from `object_list`. Apologies.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: no problems! :)